# JavaFX - Update Table Row From Task

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to update the text in my table from inside my JavaFx Task. I've done this before with basic labels, but I'm completely lost when it comes to properly binding to the table and updating the rows. Here is the code I have so far.

My main class

```
public class AnotherClass extends Application {
static List<Listing> listings = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Listing>());
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // calls init function about 200 lines of code for adding Listing objects to the listings list.

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

My controller class:

```
public class TestController implements Initializable {

UpdateTableTask updateTableTask = new UpdateTableTask(); 

@FXML
public TableView<Listing> allListings; 
@FXML
public TableColumn<Listing, String> nameCol;
public TableColumn<Listing, String> idCol;
public TableColumn<Listing, String> skuCol;
@FXML
public final ObservableList<Listing> allListingsData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {



    for(int i = 0; i < AnotherClass.listings.size(); i++){

        allListingsData.add(AnotherClass.listings.get(i)); 
    }
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Listing, String>("name"));
    idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Listing, String>("id"));
    skuCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Listing, String>("SKU"));
    allListings.setItems(allListingsData);

    updateTableTask.launch();

}   



}
```

My Listing class:

```
public class Listing {
private String name;
private String id;
private String sku;
private double maxPrice;
private double minPrice;
private double currentPrice;
private int quantity; 
private boolean isFBA; 
private boolean active;
private boolean needsUpdate = false;
private double newPrice;
private double shipping;
private boolean isCompetitive = true;
private String buyBoxName = "unknown"; 
//private String productId;
private String asin;
public Listing(String name, String id, String sku, double minPrice, double maxPrice, double currentPrice, int quantity, String asin, boolean isFBA, boolean active, double shipping){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id; 
    this.sku = sku;
    this.maxPrice = maxPrice;
    this.minPrice = minPrice; 
    this.currentPrice = currentPrice;
    this.quantity = quantity;        
    this.isFBA = isFBA; 
    this.active = active;
    this.shipping = shipping;
    //this.productId = productId;
    this.asin = asin;
  }
  public String getShippingLabel(){
     String result;
      if(Double.compare(this.shipping, 0.0) == 0){
            result = "Standard Free Shipping";
       }else{
            result = "Default Amazon Template"; 
       }
       return result;
   }
   public String getASIN(){
        return this.asin; 
   }
    public String getName(){
       return this.name;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getQuantity(){
       return this.quantity;  
    }
    public boolean getNeedsUpdate(){
        return this.needsUpdate;
    }


    public void setNeedsUpdate(boolean b){
        this.needsUpdate = b; 
    }

    public void setNewPrice(double price){
        this.newPrice = price;
    }

    public double getNewPrice(){
        return this.newPrice; 
    }

    public String getSKU(){
        return this.sku; 
    }

    public double getCurrentPrice(){
        return this.currentPrice;
    }

   public void setCurrentPrice(double price){
        this.currentPrice = price; 
    }

    public boolean getIsFBA(){
       return this.isFBA;
   }

    public void setIsFBA(boolean isFBA){
        this.isFBA = isFBA;
    }

    public double getMinPrice(){
        return this.minPrice; 
    }

    public double getMaxPrice(){
        return this.maxPrice;
    }

    public double getShipping(){
        return this.shipping; 
    }

    public void setIsCompetitive(boolean isCompetitive){
        this.isCompetitive = isCompetitive;
    }

    public boolean getIsCompetitive(){
        return this.isCompetitive; 
    }

    public void setNewPriceToMin(){
        this.newPrice = this.minPrice; 
    }

    public void setNewPriceToMax(){
        this.newPrice = this.maxPrice; 
    }

    public void setBuyBoxName(String name){
        this.buyBoxName = name; 
    }

    public String getBuyBoxName(){
        return this.buyBoxName; 
    }
}
```

Then I have a task that I need to update the table with.

```
public class UpdateTableTask extends Service<Void>{

@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                  while(true){
                       synchronized(AnotherClass.listings){
                          for(int i = 0; i < AnotherClass.listings.size(); i++){
                              // multiple threads access the list.
                               Response response = makeAPICall();
                              listings.get(i).isCompetitive(response); //true or false
                              Thread.sleep(1000);
                          }

                       }
                  }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

(manually typed in the code)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is this in a background thread? You will need to do the actual update on the FX Application Thread. To update, you should just call some method on the appropriate `Listing` instance, assuming your `Listing` class uses JavaFX properties.

Comment: The thread hits an API every second and updates a List of Listing Objects. That's why its in a thread. I would like for it to update directly from the thread so that I can also display error messages if there is an issue with the response for data on a certain row. My listing class only contains getters and setters.

Comment: If you don't use JavaFX properties, then you will have to call `allListings.refresh()` after you change the `Listing` object (by calling the appropriate `set` method). That will be pretty inefficient. If you use JavaFX properties there is no need for that, and the appropriate cells will respond. In any rate, essentially all you need to do is set the value of the `Listing` object, just on the FX application thread (using `Platform.runLater()`). Can you show what you have tried? It's impossible to know why it's not working without seeing what you have done.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet because I am unsure what to do. I like your method of binding so that the cell automatically updates via a listener. But I'm unsure of how to do that. I've updated all of my code to show more of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit hard as your code as presented is a bit incomplete and wouldn't actually compile, so I will modify things a little bit and make some assumptions (which may not match your actual use case).

Let's assume you want have a column:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Listing, String> isCompetitiveCol;
```

For which you have a propertyValueFactory:

```
isCompetitiveCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Listing, String>("isCompetitive"));
```

Change your Listing class to use full JavaFX properties, rather than just basic types.  For example, instead of:

```
private boolean isCompetitive = true;
. . .
public void setIsCompetitive(boolean isCompetitive){
    this.isCompetitive = isCompetitive;
}
public boolean getIsCompetitive(){
    return this.isCompetitive; 
}
```

Write:

```
private BooleanProperty isCompetitive = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
public void setIsCompetitive(boolean isCompetitive){
    this.isCompetitive.set(isCompetitive);
}
public boolean getIsCompetitive(){
    return this.isCompetitive.get(); 
}
public BooleanProperty isCompetitiveProperty() {
    return isCompetitive;
}
```

This turns the competitive property into a listenable property that can fire change and invalidation listeners when its value is updated.  The [PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) implementation will trigger the update notification (and subsequent update to a value in a cell in the table), whenever the property is changed.

As you using threads, you need to make sure that you *don't update the isCompetitive property value off of the JavaFX application thread* (as updates to the scene graph triggered from the property update can only occur on the JavaFX application thread).  You can do that by running any updates using [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html).

So your task can be something like this:

```
@FXML
public TableView<Listing> allListings; 
...
for(int i = 0; i < AnotherClass.listings.size(); i++){
    allListingsData.add(new Listing(AnotherClass.listings.get(i))); 
}
...
return new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
         while(true){
              synchronized(AnotherClass.listings) {
                  for(int i = 0; i < AnotherClass.listings.size(); i++){
                      Response response = makeAPICall();
                      Platform.runLater(() -> {
                          allListings.getItems().get(i).setIsCompetitive(
                              response.isCompetitive()
                          );
                      }; 
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                  }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Note, I am keeping the listing objects in the TableView items separate from the listing objects in the `AnotherClass.listings` class (by creating the list using `allListingsData.add(new Listing(AnotherClass.listings.get(i)));`).  This is to ensure that when if you have other threads updating `AnotherClass.listings` values, it doesn't have a side effect of trying to update your table through the linkage established via the PropertyValueFactory.  Instead updates are transferred from `AnotherClass.listings` to the TableView in the platform.runLater call to make sure the table only changes when you need to have it change.

Note the above solution is assuming a fixed list of listings where the values of the properties of the listings change, but the number and order of listings themselves don't change (e.g. listings are not added to, removed from or reordered in the list during the process).  If that assumption is does not hold, then you will need additional logic to update the list values themselves, and not just the properties inside list elements (and to be careful to do so without violating threading rules).  To understand how to achieve that you can look the [Task documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) sections about tasks which return ObservableLists, Partial Results Tasks and Tasks which modify the Scene Graph and will likely need to use some combination of the idioms described in those samples to achieve the result you require.

Also note, because you are just doing `while(true)` in your Task, you probably don't even need a Task (as you are not using any of it's features, such as the return value, updateMessage and updateProgress systems).  Instead you can just launch a thread with a runnable (either new Thread() or using Executors) and update values back via Platform.runLater as needed.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks!!